# How do I create a plone and volto project

Tags: plone

so, I'm participating on a interview and the goal is to create a simple component in plone/volto but I don't have any idea on how to do this... I know how to write the code but can't even get to do this cause I don't have any idea on how to set up the project. any video or tutorial is welcome

I tried it with docker but i cant acess the code and npm gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going to https://training.plone.org/ and checking out either the "Volto Training":

https://training.plone.org/volto/index.html

or the "Mastering Plone 6" training (which is a bit more extensive):

https://training.plone.org/mastering-plone/index.html#mastering-plone-label